# Swift core data many-to-many relationship not saving entities

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I use the following code to add a `pokemon` entity to the `pokemons` relationship in `user` where `pk` is an `NSManagedObject` of type `pokemon`

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {                 return         }
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest <NSManagedObject>
(entityName: "User")
let pokemonRequest = NSFetchRequest <NSManagedObject>
(entityName: "Pokemon")

let manyRelation = user.value(forKeyPath: "pokemons") as! NSMutableSet
manyRelation.add(pk)

do {                 
    try managedContext.save()             
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print ("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

The application shows the `user` has a pokemon entity in the `pokemons` relationship. I move to the profile view to view your pokemons with the following code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController        
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
```

Where I load the user data with this code:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {                 return         }
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest <NSManagedObject>
(entityName: "User")
do {
    let users = try managedContext.fetch (fetchRequest)
    for user in users {
        let name = user.value (forKey: "username")
        as? String let pks = user.value (forKey: "pokemons")
        as? NSMutableSet if name = = username {
            for pokemon in pks! {
                self.pokemonsList.append (pokemon as! NSManagedObject)
            }
        }
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print ("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

However, the `pks` variable is always empty. Why is the variable always empty? The `user` variable does have `pokemons` filled with:

```
pokemons = "<relationship fault: 0x600001726da0 'pokemons'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is to forget to `save` the managed object context after you modify it. A managed object context is just a workspace... if you don't save it, your changes never make it into the persistent store, and you won't see your changes when you later make a fetch request. So... make sure you're saving the context and any parent contexts.

Comment: after adding to the manyRelation I do: try managedContext.save()

Comment: You should show that code and also the code that checks for errors.